# Replace/delete key3.db in Firefox profile from an extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

My Firefox extension needs to replace/delete `key3.db` in the Firefox profile, is there a way to do that? I tried to `nsIFile.copyTo()` but the file is not overwritten, `nsIFile.remove()` but it returns `NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED`.

Answer (score 1):

No, replacing a file while it's being used isn't a good idea. Instead you should be using the XPCOM functionality meant to manipulate this file (meaning the master password). Something like this should work:

```js
var pk11db = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/security/pk11tokendb;1"]
                       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPK11TokenDB);
var token = pk11db.getInternalKeyToken();
token.changePassword("", "foobar");
```

Using `""` instead of `"foobar"` should remove the master password. However, I'm not entirely sure that changing the master password will work without querying the current password. Firefox Mobile can be used as a relatively simple [code example](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/dc5c600d5fe3/mobile/xul/chrome/content/MasterPasswordUI.js).

Comment: Thanks, but suppose I have another key3.db file, is it possible to copy the content of that file to the current key3.db file? I tried to search but could not find any answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even through XPCOM components?

Comment: As I said - you can set a different password. You cannot work on the file level.